# Rails routing not recognizing action call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

a route is defined as such:

```
  post '/shopkeepers/confirm_budgets', to: 'shopkeepers#confirm_budgets', as: 'shopkeepers_confirm_budgets'
```

I am not keen on the syntaxic approach, but being a legacy application...  It is rendered in rake routes as:

```
 shopkeepers_confirm_budgets POST       /shopkeepers/confirm_budgets(.:format)                              shopkeepers#confirm_budgets
```

the form is calling:

```
<%= form_tag('shopkeepers_confirm_budgets_path', remote: true) do %>
```

the following also fails

```
<%= form_tag('confirm_budgets_shopkeepers_path', remote: true) do %>
```

The application fails to recognize it:

```
Started POST "/shopkeepers/shopkeepers_confirm_budgets_path" for ::1 at 2020-09-13 10:22:22 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/shopkeepers/shopkeepers_confirm_budgets_path"):
```

However if I flip matters around with a button_to, the process runs.

```
<%= button_to shopkeepers_confirm_budgets_path, remote: true, params: {criteria: "#{shop.id}", value: number_with_precision(available_funds.to_d/100, precision: 2)} do %>
<% end %>
```

Why is the form not processing the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing it as a string, not as a method. Remove the quotes and it works.

```
<%= form_tag confirm_budgets_shopkeepers_path, remote: true do %>
```